# How to get the bounding box x y coordinates of the detected faces

Tags: python

I'm working for face detection application. 
I need to get the bounding box coordinates of every detected face in an image. 
This is the code and the problem is it print bbox coordinate for one face only in a scenario where there were many faces detected.

```
import mxnet as mx
import cv2
import os

detector = MtcnnDetector(model_folder='model', ctx=mx.cpu(0))
img = cv2.imread("amm.png")
results = detector.detect_face(img, False)
t2 = time.time() -t1
print("time: ",t2) 
if results is not None:
total_boxes = results[0]
points = results[1]
draw = img.copy()
for b in total_boxes:
    cv2.rectangle(draw, (int(b[0]), int(b[1])), (int(b[2]), int(b[3])),(250, 100, 0),1)
face_count = 0   # counting  number of detected faces within the image
for b in total_boxes:
     face_count +=1
print("detected faces" , face_count) # printing number of detected faces.
# I want to print the x and y  coordinates of every faces detected
for z in b :
    print(int(z), end=" ", flush=True)
```

So this is the results  I  got:

detected faces 12
199 302 257 377 0  (this bbox for only one face whereas 12 faces detected )

Could someone help me to figure out how to get the bboxes for all detected faces?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over `total_boxes` for printing the coordinates.

Replace `for z in b :` with `for z in total_boxes :`

So your updated code should be something like

`for box in total_boxes:
    for coord in box:
        print(int(coord), end=" ", flush=True)
    print()`

Comment: Thank you Hari  for your respond,  I did iterated as you explained however I got the following error:     detected faces 13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modifiing.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(int(z), end=" ", flush=True)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Yes boss, it is working as magic.  Thank you so much dear friend :-). So I have to use nested  for loop.

Comment: I got the desired output as :    ""detected faces 13
1848 404 1982 576 0
1407 711 1591 939 0
1688 461 1779 570 0
2133 766 2313 964 0
2372 586 2491 745 0
2750 391 2851 521 0
1646 697 1813 913 0
2634 699 2773 883 0
2476 334 2576 458 0
201 1466 528 1866 0
800 1200 1043 1510 0
2046 411 2137 523 0
2523 1152 2759 1436 0

Comment: I used this code:                                                                                    
   x  ,y ,w ,h = ((int(b[0])),(int(b[1])),(int(b[2])), (int(b[3])))
  crop_img = draw[y:y+w, x:x+h]
  cv2.imwrite(str(randint(0,50))+".jpg",crop_img).

Comment: But the problem is that the cropped face coordinate is not accurate. @Hari